# Error 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Invalid format is malformed at' using jxl

Tags: java, netbeans, jxl, jexcelapi

Hello I'm trying to read a date value from an excel file using jxl, I have no problem with the other values but the date displays an error that says

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "342/Dec/17" is
>   malformed at "/Dec/17", am I missing something ?

```
public static Object[][] readRegisters(String file) throws IOException, BiffException {

          ArrayList<Object[]> response = new ArrayList();
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(file));
        String[] names = workbook.getSheetNames();
        int shSrv = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].toLowerCase().equals("registers")) {
                shSrv = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (shSrv < 0) {
            errores.error("file doesn't contain a sheet called registers");
            return new Object[0][0];
        }
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(shSrv);

        Cell[] row = sheet.getRow(0);

        int idsrv = -1;
        int sup = -1;
        int ver = -1;
        int pag = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            Cell cell = row[i];
            if (cell.getContents().equals("ID")) {
                idsrv = i;
            }
            if (cell.getContents().equals("DATE")) {
                sup = i;
            }           
            if (cell.getContents().equals("MONEY")) {
                pag = i;
            }

        }
        if ((idsrv < 0) || (sup < 0) || (pag < 0) ) {
            errores.error("columns name error");
            return new Object[0][0];
        }     

//THIS IS WHERE I READ THE DATE > DateTime.parse((row[sup].getContents()))
        for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);            
            response.add(new Object[]{DateTime.parse(row[sup].getContents()),Integer.parseInt(row[idsrv].getContents()), Integer.parseInt(row[pag].getContents()) > 0 });

        }

        Object[][] table = createBiArrayFromArrayList(response);
        return table;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (kinda) , the 'solution' was to change the format of the column in the excel file from date to string